# ffmpeg: Create a Videofile from a DVD using a loop (DVD-Rip)

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a DVD with a movie contained in the following 4 files:

```
D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_1.VOB
D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_2.VOB
D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_3.VOB
D:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_01_4.VOB
```

The movie is offered in several languages.

With the following command I create an `mkv-file` (that contains all languages ​​of the film selectable):

```
   ffmpeg -i "concat:VTS_01_1.VOB|VTS_01_2.VOB|VTS_01_3.VOB|VTS_01_4.VOB"     ^
    -vcodec libx265 -map 0:a -map 0:v     ^
    C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\new-video-h265.mkv
```

(added hats `^` for linebreaks)

**Question**: Is it somehow  possible to make this with a loop?

Comment: Why do you think a loop is simpler than a 1 line command?

Comment: @DavidPostill The shown method works, but I ask just for technically interests. I would find a solution interesting.